# How to change results to arrays?

Tags: php

I have result from query:

```
array (
  [0]=>array (
    "id"=>"3"
    "role_id"=>  "62"
    "user_id"=> "20"
    "service_id"=> "1"
    "field_id"=> "4"
    "value"=> "asdfgh"
  )
  [1]=>array (
    "id"=> "4"
    "role_id"=> "62"
    "user_id"=> "20"
    "service_id"=> "2"
    "field_id"=> "3"
    "value"=> "qwerty"
  )
  [2]=>array (
    "id"=> "5"
    "role_id"=> "62"
    "user_id"=> "20"
    "service_id"=> "2"
    "field_id"=>  "4"
    "value"=>  "asdfgh"
  )
  [3]=>array (
    "id"=> "6"
    "role_id"=> "62"
    "user_id"=> "20"
    "service_id"=> "2"
    "field_id"=> "16"
    "value"=>  "zxcvbn"
  )
)
```

And I want to arrange this data like this:

```
$roles = array(
    'services' => array(
         [2] => array( // this [2] is service_id
             'fields'=>array(
                 [0]=>array(
                     "id"=>"16", "value"=>"zxcvbn"
                 )
                 [1]=>array(
                     "id"=>"4", "value"=>"asdfgh"
                 )
                 [2]=>array(
                     "id"=>"3", "value"=>"qwerty"
                 )
              )
         [1] => array( // this [1] is service_id
             'fields'=>array(
                 [0]=>array(
                     "id"=>"4", "value"=>"asdfgh"
                 )
              )
          )
      )
 )
```

Result is sorted first by role_id then by service_id.

I want to show table where each row is a separate role, in row I want to show fields grouped by service.

How to do it?

I'm stuck here:

```
$roles = array();
foreach($resultArray as $ra){
    $roles[$ra['role_id']] = array(
       ...
    )
}
```

Now I'm thinking...

```
$temp_role = null;
$roles = array();
foreach($resultArray as $ra){
    if($ra['role_id']!=$temp_role){
        $temp_role = $ra['role_id']
        ... something like this, but is it a good idea?
```

Comment: What was your attempt to get it into your expected ending array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go;

[PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ja7-b50)

```
<?php
$initial = array (
  0=>array (
    "id"=>"3",
    "role_id"=>  "62",
    "user_id"=> "20",
    "service_id"=> "1",
    "field_id"=> "4",
    "value"=> "asdfgh"
  ),
  1=>array (
    "id"=> "4",
    "role_id"=> "62",
    "user_id"=> "20",
    "service_id"=> "2",
    "field_id"=> "3",
    "value"=> "qwerty"
  ),
  2=>array (
    "id"=> "5",
    "role_id"=> "62",
    "user_id"=> "20",
    "service_id"=> "2",
    "field_id"=>  "4",
    "value"=>  "asdfgh"
  ),
  3 =>array (
    "id"=> "6",
    "role_id"=> "62",
    "user_id"=> "20",
    "service_id"=> "2",
    "field_id"=> "16",
    "value"=>  "zxcvbn"
  )
);

$roles = array(
    'services' => array()
);

foreach($initial as $key => $value) {
    if (!isset($roles['services'][$value['service_id']]['fields'])) {
        $roles['services'][$value['service_id']]['fields'] = array();
    }

    $roles['services'][$value['service_id']]['fields'][] = array(
        'id' => $value['field_id'],
        'value' => $value['value']
    );
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($roles);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [services] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [fields] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4
                                    [value] => asdfgh
                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [fields] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 3
                                    [value] => qwerty
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4
                                    [value] => asdfgh
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 16
                                    [value] => zxcvbn
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Your answer is the first time I've encountered [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org). Looks much more featureful than [Codepad](http://codepad.org) and other similar tools. That's an upvote!

Answer (score 1):

[phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ydn-tkb)

```
    $services = array();

    foreach ($resultArray as $v) {
       if( ! isset($services[$v['service_id']] )) {  
          $services[$v['service_id']] = array('fields' => array()); 
       } 
       $services[$v['service_id']]['fields'][] = array( 'id' => $v['field_id'], 'value' => $v['value']);
    }

    $roles = array('services' => $services);
```